Anime about a dark-haired main character with chains around his heart and magical beasts inside him, set on a platform island in Japan
I remember very little of this anime, but I will share what I do know. The main character was a guy who had chains around his heart. There were magical beasts inside him.
I saw this ages ago, I'm pretty sure on a site that no longer exists or got shut down, which definitely makes it harder to find. If I had to try and pinpoint when I watched it, I'd say around 2018, but I don't know when the show was made.
I remember the main character having darker hair. The chains around his heart broke, and he kind of went berserk with the power of the beast inside him. Also, a main thing I remember was that I think it's set in Japan, where the place he lives is like a platform island able to detach and reattach for ships or whatever.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Motifs of chains, hearts and beasts make me think of Pandora Hearts, but I don't know if it exactly fits your recollections.

I saw this ages ago I’m pretty sure on a site that no longer exists/got shut down so that definitely makes it harder if I had to try and pinpoint it id say around 2018 but I don’t know when the show was made

I looked around at it a bit and it seems like it’s not what I was looking for, something else that might help is that I remember him having darker hair and the chains around his heart broke and he kind of went berserk with the power of the beast inside of him also a main thing I remember was I think it is set in Japan where the place he lives on is like a platform island able to detach and reattach for ships of what ever
